# What is the procedure to Import word2vec model written in C++ using H2O framework?

Tags: scala, word2vec, h2o

Using H2O is mandatory, Perform Embedding on the text file(dataset as input) using word2vec  model to produce an output as Vectors(arrays).
The word2Vec model will be using is below-https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/
which is written in C/C++.
So, how can one implement using H2O?

Comment: By "implement" do you mean you want to load pre-generated word-embeddings into H2O, but then use, say, `findSynonyms` from inside h2o?

Comment: Yes, that will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[ If using H2O is "mandatory" for you, are you perhaps using it in a course?  If so, I'm curious where that is... ]

H2O-3 is written in Java, and has an internal word2vec implementation written from scratch in Java.  You wouldn't actually use the referenced C++ implementation inside of H2O-3.

Here is a pointer to the relevant word2vec documentation for H2O-3:

- http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/word2vec.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate the previous model as csv, import the csv as a frame and construct the w2oModel and specify the data frame as pretrained parameter.